# AngularJS $http POST received as null variable in Java controller backend

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

Im looking to send data from AngularJS to use it later in the Python+Java backend. The issue is that it gets sent as null, and I cant figure out why. There are no errors at the console from google chrome, but I can see the problem in my java server console (mvn -P dev), where im using return to see what's the value of the variable at arrival:

> DEBUG 13496 --- [XNIO-23 task-27] a.c.p.s.aop.logging.LoggingAspect: Exit: us.com.generic.web.rest.DataController.getData() with result = The variable 'null' was saved

The Java Controller, getting information from AngularJS:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DataController {

    @RequestMapping("/data/")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody String getData( @RequestParam(name="dataVariable", required=false) String dataVariable) {      

        return "The variable '" + dataVariable + "' was saved";
    }
}
```

The AngularJS Controller:

```
angular
    .module('Generic')
    .controller('DataController', DataController);

    DataController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'URI', '$timeout'];

    function DataController ($scope, $http, URI, $timeout) {

        var myInformation = 'HeadStreet';       

        $http.post(URI + 'api/data/', {
            dataVariable: myInformation
        }, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'charset=utf-8'
                }
            }).then(Success, Error);
        }

        function Success() {
           alert('Variable sent');
        }

        function Error() {
           alert('Issue while sending data');
        }
  }
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Spring, but it seems like your code is reading GET params, not POST params. As a quick check, try using `URI + 'api/data/?dataVariable=HeadStreet'` to very quickly find out if that's the issue. (you can also check what your request is sending client-side btw in the browser console)

Answer (score 1):

You're posting your dataVariable as json in the request's body. @RequestParam reads from the query parameters.

if you want to post the data in the body you should use @RequestBody

You need to make a POJO class like below

```
public class GetDataRequest{
   public String dataVariable;
}
```

Then in your controller

```
@RequestMapping("/data/")
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody String getData( @RequestBody GetDataRequest request) {      

    return "The variable '" + request.dataVariable + "' was saved";
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RequestParam` in your Controller, but you are sending the data in the body of the POST request.

`RequestParam` is used for a parameter in your URL, e.g. `/api/data?dataVariable=HeadStreet`, but you need to read the body of the message with `@RequestBody`, like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DataController {

    @RequestMapping("/data/")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody String getData(@RequestBody YourDTO yourDTO) String dataVariable) {      

        return "The variable '" + yourDTO.dataVariable + "' was saved";
    }
}
```

And a corresponding Data Transfer Object Class

```
class YourDTO {
    public String dataVariable;
}
```